# Decimal and deploy

Tags: erc-20

i used the following code below to create a billion TEST tokens

```
uint public constant _totalSupply = 1000000000;

    string public constant symbol = "TEST";
    string public constant name = "Test4Fun";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
```

Now when I deploy, it says I have 0.000000001000000000 TEST in my wallet... did I do something wrong? If I wanted to share 1,000 of TEST with my friends, will it show up as 1,000 TEST or 0.000000000000001000 TEST?

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong, you have to add your decimals (18 zeros) in the total supply, like this example from another coin:

`uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 100000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));`